# When does onCreateView() get called in this app?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am reading an android book and I faced an app about fragments with **ViewPager**.
I will list here the 3 classes I have my question about:

The **FragmentActivity** class:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

public class ViewPagerFragmentDemoActivity extends FragmentActivity {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ViewPager pager=findViewById(R.id.pager);

    pager.setAdapter(new SampleAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
  }
}
```

The **PagerAdapter**:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class SampleAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
  public SampleAdapter(FragmentManager mgr) {
    super(mgr);
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
    return(10);
  }

  @Override
  public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return(EditorFragment.newInstance(position));
  }
}
```

And the **Fragment** class:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class EditorFragment extends Fragment {
  private static final String KEY_POSITION="position";

  static EditorFragment newInstance(int position) {
    EditorFragment frag=new EditorFragment();
    Bundle args=new Bundle();

    args.putInt(KEY_POSITION, position);
    frag.setArguments(args);

    return(frag);
  }

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                           ViewGroup container,
                           Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View result=inflater.inflate(R.layout.editor, container, false);
    EditText editor=result.findViewById(R.id.editor);

    int position=getArguments().getInt(KEY_POSITION, -1);

    editor.setHint(String.format(getString(R.string.hint), position + 1));

    return(result);
  }
}
```

I understand that in the activity we register the SampleAdapter to be the Pager's adapter,then in the adapter every time we want to display a fragment we call getItem()  which in turn returns an EditorFragment to display on the screen,and here exactly is my problem in the method that returns this fragment.

Since this method creates an **EditorFragment()**,adds some arguments to the fragment and return the fragment to **getView()**.So when does **onCreateView()** gets called and who invokes it?

(I tried using log messages to trace the program but couldn't infer an answer to my ques.).

Edit( to specify my question more because the answers and comments were all things I already know):

"The user launches the app (let's say this app has only this **ViewPagerFragmentDemoActivity**), this activity's **onCreate()** is called,which sets the adapter,then for the first **screen** to appear,the **getView()** in the adapter class is called, which in turn calls **newInstance()** method of **EditorFragment** class, this method creates a fragment (using the constructor obviously) and adds some key-value to it using Bundle object and returns this fragment to the calling method(**getView()**)."

1.Is this trace true?

2.where is the calling of **onCreateView()** in all this?

3.What happens after the **Fragment** is returned to **getView()**?Is it at this time where android framework invokes **onCreateView()** on this object of **Fragment**?

Comment: please read it here https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments#Creating

Comment: I updated the question to clarify more what I don't understand please consider re-reading the question @HayiNukman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After your `Activity` has walked through its startup lifecycle (i.e. after `onResume()`), it will start drawing to the screen. The exact manner in which Android draws views to the screen is more complicated than it's worth getting into right here, but there will be a measurement pass done to figure out how big everything is.

That measurement pass will call `ViewPager.onMeasure()`, which will call `ViewPager.populate()` in order to know how big the `ViewPager` is.

First, `populate()` will call `ViewPager.addNewItem()`, which will call into `FragmentPagerAdapter.instantiateItem()`. This method does two things: (1) start a `FragmentTransaction` and (2) call your adapter's `getItem()` method. (This is the answer to your third question: just returning a Fragment from `getItem()` doesn't do anything... yet.)

Next, `populate()` will call `FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate()`. This method will call `commitNowAllowingStateLoss()` on the `FragmentTransaction` created above. Because it commits "now" (rather than asynchronously), this will start your Fragment.

The `FragmentManager` handles executing this `FragmentTransaction`. It will eventually call `FragmentManager.moveFragmentToExpectedState()`, which will eventually call `Fragment.performCreateView()`.

And now we're at the end of the answer. `Fragment.performCreateView()` calls your fragment's `onCreateView()` method.

Here's an image showing the whole call stack:

[image]

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for,just one more question, how do you know all these methods what "title" should I read about specifically to get to know what is happening? (I am currently reading "The Busy Coder's Guide For Android Development")

@Ben P.

Comment: I don't have a specific book to recommend. Google's developer documentation is quite good, but the source code is generally the best way to answer questions like this one.

Answer (score 1):

After the onCreate() is called (in the Fragment), the Fragment's onCreateView() is called by the system to create its view so the whole flow for a fragment would look like this and oncreateview would get called twice during its life cycle

[image]

Comment: I updated the question to clarify more what I don't understand please consider re-reading the question @Brent

Answer (score 0):

`onCreateView` is called by the Android framework when the fragment needs to create its view.

Comment: I updated the question to clarify more what I don't understand please consider re-reading the question @Henry